# I'm signed in to Multiple Google Accounts & I can use multiple services EXCEPT for email

Tags: gmail, google-account, google-workspace-for-business

I am signed in to multiple google apps accounts. When I go to gmail.com it starts out with the default acct, as expected. If I switch to acct B or C (via drop down menu on top right of the screen), the switch works as expected: I see email for acct B or C.

But when I try to switch to acct D I get a [sign in screen](https://i.imgur.com/Px2RRT7.png), **with account D LISTED as one of the signed in accts in the blurred area**.

I can successfully use other google products, such as search, with acct D on the top right of the screen.

I can also use an incognito session and successfully sign in to email at acct D, whether or not it is the default acct.

**Is this just a hiccup in the system or am I missing something?**

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved**. The accounts that had problems were the ones that had not yet fully completed the transaction from personal google acct to a organizational google account. So, even though the account created on the phone was me@mydomain.com, android was using (or being told to use) the me#mydomain.com@gtempaccount.com, which no longer had email service (the email service had been moved to the organizational account). This is why email didnt work.

**I deleted the personal acct (after moving everything that was movable to the org acct), deleted and re-created the accts on the phone, and voila.**

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Chrome? If so, you should try setting up Chrome profiles. I find them to be a much better alternative to multiple sign-in, which often crashes and isn't supported by all Google services.

Chrome profiles do use up more memory but that's about the only drawback in my experience.

Here's a video on setting them up - http://www.googlegooru.com/how-to-create-google-chrome-profiles/